# What's this style called, with blocky text and strong circle shapes?

Tags: website-design, style-identification

What's this style of design called?

http://www.mademyday.de/

[image]

Thanks.

[UPDATE:] I should have posted more examples, here's another and I'll look for more:
http://www.fajnechlopaki.com/

[image]

I'm talking about styles like "grunge" or "elegant" that if you search for you can find more designs that look like that.

Comment: Circular. I might even go for "round."

Comment: if you want a post to be deleted then you need to talk to the mods. Everything you ever did is still there, and it will get rolled back otherwise

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The style is basically [Constructivist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_%28art%29). It was a dominant style in Soviet Russia in the 30s and 40s and still influences graphic design in that part of the world today (no coincidence that your examples are German and Polish). Bauhaus and Art Deco were both influences.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can be that specific, but there's probably some Bauhaus poster design in there. Take a look at Jan Tschichold/Herbert Bayer...

Answer (score 0):

wherever i know its grid/column based design approach with a round and some modification to look **asymmetrical different** (don't know why he used round),its completely based on semi fluid layout.

- [its look like Sort of this](http://www.pelicanfly.co.uk/)
- [more examples of grid/column based
  layout](http://webdesignerwall.com/trends/grid-and-column-designs)

Mostly its designed by full page divided into desired symmetrical/asymmetrical size..horizontally /vertically depends on designer

[Detailed explantion about grid system](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/03/web-culture-grid-based-layout-designs/)

Hope it helps....